# Failure delivering result ResultInfo : com.facebook.LoginActivity

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Here is my errors

03-27 19:04:59.183: E/AndroidRuntime(8820): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=32665, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.googlemapsv2/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException